# Trouble sharing MySQL database with other machines on our network

Tags: mysql, networking, mamp

I have been trying to share a MySQL database across our internal network but I am having no luck getting it to work. I am using MAMP. I have edited the my.cnf template and commented out the bind-address line so it looks like this: `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

The IP of the machine that is hosting the MySQL database is 192.168.0.152. When I put this IP in when making a MySQL connection via PHP I get the following error:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.152' (61)
```

Obviously I am missing a step somewhere. What else am I need to do?

Comment: can you connect to it via localhost? or from the same host connecting to 192.168.0.152? what OS?

Comment: The default MySQL port for MAMP is **8889**.  Have you tried changing this port to the MySQL default of **3306** .. or connecting with a port specified (eg: `mysql -u root -h 192.168.0.152 --port 8889 -p`).  If you have a firewall enabled on the machine with the MySQL server you will also have to allow remote connections to MySQL.